# Having 2 branches on GitHub after re-login in VS Code

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have created GitHub account and repository, pushed commits under my main branch, everything was perfect. After couple of days, I needed to re-install OS. After completing with OS, I installed VS Code and all extensions again, cloned the repository, logged in with my credentials to the GitHub and after every commit, it shows the same origin Link, where my commits will be stored (in the same repository like before re-installing OS).

The issue is that right now, after following and doing the same steps like before, now all my commits goes under "Master" branch and not "Main" (default). So naturally, how could I merge both branches into Main and to have only one branch in my repository as I used to have?
[Branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wpd6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out the right approach - 1st Step: *git checkout master*. The Second step:   *git branch main master -f*. The Third step *git checkout main*. The Last step: *git push origin main -f*. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do a pull request from `master` to `main`, merge it, and then delete `master`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. If it will work, I will mark as Answered :)

Comment: I figured out, but not entirely. I already checkout at main, pulled all files from Master, so now in VS Code, I have all files up to date on my main branch. But whenever I am trying to Push something to GitHub repository, it says that "Can't push refs to remote. Try running 'Pull' first to integrate your changes". When I am trying to Pull, it gives "There is no tracking information for the current branch" and many other errors. Maybe you know the solution? Cheers